# Probability for a regular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

I was wondering: Let $P\in \mathbb{N}$ prime and $k^2 <P$. What is the probability of uniformly  drawing  $k^2$ numbers out of $\{0,1,\dots,P-1\}$ (with repetitions) such that the $k \times k$ matrix is regular, meaning - the linear transformation it represents is isomorphism.

Is this a basic probabilty question or it requires heavier tools?

Thank you.

(It's not a homework question! :-))

Comment: $k^2=P$ is not an option...

Comment: "Isomorphism" in what category? As a linear transformation of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ or as a linear transformation of $\mathbb{C}^k$, perhaps?  (The answers differ--a lot.)  Or maybe as a linear transformation of $\mathbb{F}_p^k$?

Comment: As a linear transformation above the field $\mathbb{Z}_P$